# API Gateway/NLB/ECS Latency

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs

I have a number of services deployed in ECS. They register with a Network Load Balancer (via a target group). The NLB is private, and is accessed via API Gateway + a VPC link.

Most of the time, requests to my services take ~4-5 seconds, but occasionally < 100ms. The latter should be the standard; the actual requests are served by my node instances in ~10ms or less. I'm starting to dig into this, but was wondering if there was a common bottleneck in setups similar to what I'm currently using.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this was to enable Cross-Zone Load Balancing on my load balancers. This isn't immediately obvious and took two AWS support sessions to dig it up as the root cause.

Comment: aws elbv2 modify-load-balancer-attributes --load-balancer-arn NLB_ARN_VALUE --attributes Key=load_balancing.cross_zone.enabled,Value=true